# Set background image of a webpage using HTML/CSS <html> vs <body>

Tags: html, css, background

I have an HTML file and links to a CSS file.  I got it to display a repeating background image under the CSS file by doing this (under body tag in the CSS file) and it works:

```
body {
    /*Set background image*/
    background: url("../img/background/main.jpg") repeat;
}
```

But when I try to do it this way (under html tag in the CSS file) it doesnt work:

```
html {
    /*Set background image*/
    background: url("../img/background/main.jpg") repeat;
```

According to this site it shows the example using the html tag:
[This site shows html in css being used with html tag](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

So how do I make this work, or should I NOT be doing it this way?

Comment: Be semantic my friend... The `body` is far more semantic than the `html`.

Comment: Axel is right. The BODY of the document is what you see on screen, by definition.

Comment: There's nothing semantic about what styles are applied to what tag.  If it validates, then it is valid to do so.

Comment: Can you provide a demo of this not working?  Because it looks like it works to me:  http://tinker.io/1712b

Comment: Without a real example where setting background on `html` fails, this is not a real question. Please provide a URL and specify the browser(s) tested.

Comment: @cimmanon i will post an example online when i can reconnect to school server

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela i will post an example online when i can reconnect to school server – Kairan 13 secs ago edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally considered bad practice to put CSS on the HTML tag, so you should keep it on the body tag. Usually this is for semantic reasons - the HTML element contains child elements that should not and cannot have styles applied to them (ie. the head).

Developers tend to apply styles to the HTML element out of laziness or because they don't know any better or to avoid adding additional elements to the DOM, but that doesn't make it right.

Handily, using the body element already works for you, so nbd. :)

Comment: The CSS specification specifices that background* properties *applies to all elements*:  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/colors.html#propdef-background-color.  Preferring the body element over the html element is a holdover from from the dark ages before there was CSS support.

Comment: Granted, however the fact that you can technically apply a background to any element doesn't necessarily make for semantic code. According this I could apply a background-color to the title element, but that just wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Who considers it bad practice? Why would `body` be more semantic than `html`? This answer is a collection of opinions without real arguments.