# Set transparent background in an html page

Tags: html, css

What I need is an advice or idea to solve my issue, what I want to do is to set a trasparent background such as Twenty Eleven theme of WordPress:

[image: transparent background]

I've just found that isn't a good practice to write CSS in html tag [Set background image of a webpage using HTML/CSS <html> vs <body>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980414/set-background-image-of-a-webpage-using-html-css-html-vs-body), but what in my example I'm only trying

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head><title>Opacity</title><link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></head>
<body>
This is a Test
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html{
    width:100%
    background-color:rgb(0,0,0,0.1); /*red green blue opacity */
}

body{
    max-width:300px;
    /* min-width:500px; */
    background-color: RED;
}
```

The problem is that I get a full red page, despite of the fact that I tried to set a width and also a maximum width to *body* in css.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is this http://jsfiddle.net/utwkfonx/ how your current output looks like ?

Comment: Exactly, I forgot to put the image

Comment: i think you are looking for this http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/f58advwr/3/ it is a bad practice to give css for html tag

Comment: Don't know if it fixes your problem. But you have some syntax errors in your css: `width:100%;` (missing ; ) and `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);` (rgb**A**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the height of your body is 0.

Try this:

```
html{
    width:100%;
    background: rgba(200,0,0,0.1);
    min-height: 100%;
}

body{
    background:green;
    width: 40%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Check it out here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f58advwr/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/utwkfonx/1/

HTML

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Opacity</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">This is a Test</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
html {
    width:100% background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    /*red green blue opacity */
}
body {
    background-color: RED;
}
#wrapper {
    font-size: 20px;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```